# Find only exact matches with FULLTEXT index

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, full-text-search

I have a table with phrases:

```
buy car
adopt cute cat
make big money
buy helicopter
big nasty dog
```

with a FULLTEXT index on them. I want to find all the phrases, which occur fully in the given text.

For text:

```
I want to buy car and then buy and adopt cute cat tomorrow.
```

I should get:

```
buy car
adopt cute cat
```

I tried querying:

```
SELECT * FROM `phrases` WHERE MATCH(`phrase`) AGAINST('I want to buy car and then buy and adopt cute cat tomorrow.' IN BOOLEAN MODE)=`numWords`
```

But that gives me

```
buy helicopter //since there are twice "buy" and the number of total words is 2
adopt cute cat
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so then why are you typing words like tomorrow. Sounds like you expect it to be precise, knowing it is fuzzy, and your input is more than fuzzy

Comment: I don't control the text I get. I need to find every phrase, occuring in the given text.

Comment: fair enough explanation

Comment: as I see it, you would have to abandon fulltext, and iterate with permutations with like. So it would be "I%", "I want%", "I want to%", ..., next set "want%", "want to%", "want to buy%", ...  with a union. And oh wouldn't that be a joyous thing to code

Comment: The whole point was to use the index for better performance, since the mass-LIKE algorithm will kill the server with the quantity of queries it should be able to hold.

Comment: the whole point is to not use fulltext the way you expect sir. I hardly doubt the user is clicking on helicopter result link, and will learn not to enter such broad queries to begin with

Comment: MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?  What is the min word len?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `AND phrases LIKE '%I want to buy car and then buy and adopt cute cat tomorrow.%'` to your query. It will use the FULLTEXT key to find the matches quickly, and then post-filter the results to make sure there is that exact phrase in the phrases column.

Comment: 1. The LIKE will not help in this situation, since I compare the other side, I will not find the full text in the phrases only table.
2. Even if I use LOCATE(`phrase`,'I want........') > 0 it will not give me the needed result, since it was filtered out by MATCH AGAINST